# Adding CDN in NextJs 13 project not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cdn, next.js13

When I want to add a CDN such as the Remix Icon one in my NextJs13 project, it doesn't work, I was researching and the way it is done is import, the "head" tag and then put the values ​​inside the Head component, but that's already It doesn't work and it was migrated to another way which I don't know how to do it, if someone knows great, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you edit your question to include some code? It's easier for us to help you if we know your environment.
[I can also recommend reading "How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously on Next `Pages Router` you could create a `_document.tsx` file. On that file you would import `Head` component & add link to your CDN.

```js
<Html>
    <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.8.0/styles/nord.min.css" />
    </Head>
    <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
```

But on new Next.js 13 `App Router` you can add the link to CDN on root `layout.tsx` file, like below

```js
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.8.0/styles/nord.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body> {children} </body>
</html>
```